# Office Script - get column number using column name

Tags: javascript, excel, typescript, office365, office-scripts

New to office scripts, and currently have a script that filters in a specific column.
Currently it's set to look in the 10th column, but the report I get is sometimes modified such that it could be in a different place (but always the same name).
Would appreciate any help so that the script looks for the column header named "market"...

```js
selectedSheet.getAutoFilter().apply(selectedSheet.getAutoFilter().getRange(), 10, { filterOn: ExcelScript.FilterOn.values, values: ["city1"] });
```

This script runs as part of a flow when a certain file is received from corporate. The corporate folks like to update the order of columns... which results in incorrect filtering...

Answer (score 2):

You can try the code below:

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
  let sh = workbook.getWorksheet("Sheet1")
  let r = sh.getUsedRange().find("market",{completeMatch:true,matchCase:false})
  let marketColumnNumber = r.getColumnIndex()
  selectedSheet.getAutoFilter().apply(selectedSheet.getAutoFilter().getRange(), marketColumnNumber, { filterOn: ExcelScript.FilterOn.values, values: ["city1"] });
}
```

The code searches for the "market" keyword and assigns the column index for that column to a variable called `marketColumnNumber`. From there you can just update your original code to use the `marketColumnNumber` instead of the hardcoded 10 value.

Comment: Thank you! Can I use "workbook.getActiveWorkheet () in case the sheet name changes?

Comment: Yes that should be fine. You just have to update the sh variable like this `let selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet()` Be careful with using getActiveWorksheet() with a workbook with multiple worksheets. You may get unexpected results.

Comment: wonderful! and one more... sorry... since "sh" would no longer be used, how would it read on the "let r" line?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo on my part. The part to update should be `let sh = workbook.getActiveWorksheet()`

Comment: @KileyMurphy if you are satisfied with the answer, please flag it to reflect that and reward the contributor who has answered it.